# Unread/Read Notification Badges in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to have a notification badges (web-based) that can read and unread, well I don't know what's the right term for that, but imagine facebook notification, when you had 3 notification, it will show 3 badge. Well here's the site so you can understand better http://getbootstrap.com/components/#badges. What I need is that, If I click a certain button, the notification badge will disappear.

Here's my button code

```html
<a class='btn btn-default btn-xs' href='#' role='button'>View Notification</a>
```

and here's my code with notification badge, well dont try to run it, because you can see the bootstrap design :(

```html
<a href="index.php?cat=notifications" >Notifications<span class="badge">1</span></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Since you are using bootstrap, and bootstrap plugins requires [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), I will assume that you are also using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).*

---

You should first give the View Notification button and the notification badge an `id`, unless there is only a single button and a single badge on the page.

[Then you can simply register an event handler for when someone clicks your button to hide the badge.](http://jsfiddle.net/utdhx2Lg/)

```
$('#view-notification').click(function() {
    $('#notification-badge').hide();
});
```

Comment: well the View Notification and the Notification are in different page, I tried this but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @Vista You should have stated that in your question. However, if that is the case, your question is probably too board. You would need to update a database when someone clicks the view notification button. Then [tag:php] will have to check whether the button has been clicked based on the value in the database and show it or hide it.

Comment: oops I'm terribly sorry It works now!, I just need to put the javascript on on my index.php. Thank you very much! :D